# jquery char count Validation

Tags: jquery, char, counter, jquery-validate

I was hoping I could find a jquery plugin that counted the chars of a certain textfield or textArea that would also do some kind of validation as well...  You know, if the input field was over 4000 chars the form won't submit and display an error text right next to it.  Nice to have, but not necessary, like a live countdown till to many chars have been used.  I was hoping that jquery.validation plugin would handle that in some way.  Or perhaps I need to write it myself.

Comment: And what have you tried? What options have you found on the web so far? What success did you have with jQuery.validation?

Comment: Writing a character counter is really simple.

Comment: -3?  Yikes.  You guys on the warpath?  I thought it was an ok question.  I am currently looking through jquery.Validation documentation for that functionality.  Can't seem to find it immediatly.  Come to think of it, these comments fields have the functionality that I am looking for.  Hey stack Overflow guys, what do you use for your comments character count/validation?

Comment: must have offended the wrong people, or horses

Comment: not a bad question but people seem to be not in the holiday spirit with down voting this week :-)

Comment: agreed, voting it back up to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, use something like this: http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas,

then, write your own check on submit:

```
// assuming you have a <span> on the page with class of "counter"
// <span class="counter"></span>
$(function(){
  $("#myform").submit(function(){
    var count = parseInt($("span.counter").text());
    if (count < 4000) {
      // show error to the user and block submission of the form
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of doing.  I wouldn't necessarily write my own .submit, I am using jquery Validation, but that first pluggin is kind of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few I found off *Google*:

- http://that-matt.com/2010/04/updated-textarea-maxlength-with-jquery-plugin/
- http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/
- http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/maxlength-for-textarea-with-jquery/
- http://www.devcurry.com/2009/08/limit-number-of-characters-in-textarea.html
- http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/enforceform.shtml

Even off Stackoverflow..

- [limit how many characters can be pasted in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190420/limit-how-many-characters-can-be-pasted-in-textarea)

Remember to do your homework!

Comment: Found those as well.  I was hoping for functionality in jquery.Validation, as I am using it for other fields right now...

Comment: Can you not simply add the functionality you want to the existing plugin you use to validate with?

Comment: I could, but I guess what I really should ask is would I be reinventing the wheel if I did that.  Like I said earlier, the functionality that I am looking for is actually in the comments section of this site.  So It's obviously been done before.  I don't want to have to re-write if there is already a good pluggin out there for it.

Comment: Thus my suggested methods. You could merely implement the function within a `$.extend()` in your plugin file.