# OpenCart - Form character limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, opencart

OpenCart 1.5.1.3 I have tried putting some suggestion into play, but they do not seem to work with OpenCart`<?php } elseif ($field['type'] == 'textarea') { ?>
                            <textarea name="<?php echo $key; ?>" style="width: 40%; height: 50px"><?php echo ${$key}; ?></textarea><br />`
It's complicated by the factor there are more than one textarea, and I want to be able to set the limit for specific one "message"

Comment: Hi Laura. You're going to need to explain a bit clearer what it is you are wanting. At the minute this is very hard to understand

Comment: Sorry,  Have a form in opencart and I want to limit the number of characters in one textbox.  I just copies the piece from the tmp that had the textarea.  Not sure how best to put it {<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
  <?php } elseif ($field['type'] == 'textarea') { ?>
       <textarea name="<?php echo $key; ?>" style="width: 40%; height: 50px"><?php echo ${$key}; ?></textarea><br />}  I would like to be able to put a limit on the number of characters the end user can enter, or at least a counter so they know how much is left, just like they user her

Comment: See that you are an OpenCart person, I bought a form extension and I would like to put into place text counter, if possible counter.  I tried placing some javascript solution (works fine on it's own) but it did not work with the opencart form - normal and extension.

Comment: To be honest, that is more of a jquery/javascript question (OC has JQuery by default). I'll retag to give your post more visibility

Comment: thank you hopefully that will help

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:

- http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/
- http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2007/11/09/interactive-character-limit-for-textarea-using-jquery/
- [limit how many characters can be pasted in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190420/limit-how-many-characters-can-be-pasted-in-textarea)